# Using a Boolean statement in matplotlib -- graph only TRUE values

Tags: csv, matplotlib, graph, boolean, crosstab

I'm trying to create a graph based on data from a csv file. I need to show on the graph only the # of instances a certain name, let's call it `JOE` appear in the dataset across a set of years which are listed in the csv file under the column title `DATA_YEAR`

```
HC = pd.read_csv(filename)
pd.crosstab(HC['DATA_YEAR'], HC['COLUMN2_TITLE'] == 'JOE').plot(kind='bar')
```

It works except the graph shows "True" and "False" results, whereas I only want the "True" ones to show. Can someone help? I'm very new to coding!!